# Cannot remove a string from an array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist

I'm trying to populate an array of file paths where ever the script is located in. But I don't want
the array to include the path of the script only the other files in that folder. I have tried removing it after it is populated by using a list array instead but then I get an error that the array is a fixed size.

```
#To get path in which the script is located
$mypath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$myStringPath=$mypath.ToString().Replace("TestingScriptPath.ps1", "")
```

```
#Populates files inside the folder
$array = @() 
(Get-ChildItem -Path $myStringPath ).FullName |
foreach{
    $array += $_ 
    
}
```

```
#display paths
for($i = 0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++)
{ 
 
 $array[$i]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off not putting it in the array in the first place.

When updating an array the whole array has to be rewritten, so the performance tends to be terrible.

Use a different datatype if you're going to be removing item-by-item.

```
#To get path in which the script is located
$mypath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$myStringPath=$mypath.ToString().Replace("testingscriptpath.ps1", "")

#Populates files inside the folder
$array = Get-ChildItem -Path $myStringPath | Where-Object {$_.fullname -ne $mypath}

$array
```

if you definitely want to do it the way suggested in the question (slower)

```
$ArrayWithFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $myStringPath
$ArrayWithoutFile = $ArrayWithFile | Where-Object {$_.fullName -ne $mypath}
```